# Partitioning tuples

Tags: reference-request, partitions

Given are tuples $(a_{11},\dots,a_{1k}), (a_{21},\dots,a_{2k}), \dots, (a_{n1},\dots,a_{nk})$. We want to know if there is a partition of the tuples into two parts, so that for every coordinate $i=1,\dots,k$, the sum of each part is equal to the sum of the other part.

Has this problem been studied before? If $k=1$, it is of course the famous [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). But I cannot find this generalization under the section "Variants and generalizations" in the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same problem as partition. Let $M$ be a large enough integer, and replace each tuple $(a_{i1},\ldots,a_{ik})$ with the single integer $\sum_j a_{ij} M^j$. You now have an equivalent instance of PARTITION.

Your problem appears in the literature, under the name *multidimensional two-way number partitioning*, in Jelena Kojić, [Integer linear programming model for multidimensional two-way number partitioning problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122110005882).